# How to display all commands of the bash shell in a file? Linux

Tags: linux, bash

So I have an assignment in linux terminal asking me to create a file in the home directory and to make the file display all the commands of the bash shell which is found in the /bin directory.

I already tried to use the echo command to display the commands to the file but it is not working:

```
echo $ls /bin > File1
```

I expect that the file contains all the commands of the bash shell, but when I type the line above in the linux terminal, the content of the file is just the word "/bin".

Is there any other way to use to meet the expected result?

Comment: You have homework for a reason, and it does not belong to the community to do it for you.

Comment: @LéaGris at least I've tried to find the solution by my self first and i think that this website is meant to find solutions for all our programming problems.

Comment: Your answer --a winner for sure-- should be something along the lines "the question doesn't make much sense; there are no *commands of the bash shell* in the /bin directory, besides (maybe) `bash` itself, of course".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you don't need the echo command, as ls already prints to standard output, which can then be piped to the file. The command you want is:

```
ls /bin > File1
```

A good way to go about this is by checking that "ls /bin" by itself will print to standard output the contents of /bin, and once you see the expected output, run it again with the "> File1" to then output to File1.